# Getting extra lines Python print output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python. I have made a script to capture the active Window title and print it to the console. I added timestamp and user. Here is what I have

```
import win32gui
import datetime
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()

windowTile = ""; 
while ( True ) :
    newWindowTile = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow());        
    if(newWindowTile != windowTile) :
        ts = datetime.datetime.now()
        windowTile = newWindowTile
        line =str(ts) + ' ' + user + ' ' + newWindowTile
        #line = newWindowTile
        print(line)
```

The output is as follows

```
2020-09-03 13:34:16.075329 Eric Spyder (Python 3.8)
2020-09-03 13:34:18.208329 Eric 
2020-09-03 13:34:18.279376 Eric COM5 - PuTTY
2020-09-03 13:34:18.877347 Eric 
2020-09-03 13:34:18.955382 Eric Spyder (Python 3.8)
2020-09-03 13:34:19.592409 Eric 
2020-09-03 13:34:19.631369 Eric COM5 - PuTTY
```

Why do I get the extra line output with blank info?

Comment: Guessing the Desktop is considered a "window"

Comment: Never thought of it that way.

Comment: It's running as `explorer.exe`. If you kill that, then you kill everything else except other active windows.

Comment: As an aside, there is no reason to put `True` in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you toggle between windows, say Alt-Tab, then it's briefly cycling to the "Desktop" window, which very likely doesn't have a name. Simply clicking between two windows, I don't think you'd see those lines.

Assuming you want to ignore it, or anything else with no title, then you can use `if newWindowTitle` to see if that new string is non-empty

```
newWindowTile = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow());        
if newWindowTitle and newWindowTile != windowTile:
    ts = datetime.datetime.now()
    windowTile = newWindowTile
    line =str(ts) + ' ' + user + ' ' + newWindowTile
    #line = newWindowTile
    print(line)
```

Comment: Clicking between Windows I still seem to see the lines, but your answer does help explain and accomplish what I want. Thanks,